# Create an account Firebase x Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to put in place, in my ionic application, an authentification system(sign in and register), but there is a problem.
Indeed, this is my code :

```js
exampleApp.controller("LoginController", function($scope, $firebaseAuth, $location) {
 
    $scope.login = function(username, password) {
        var fbAuth = $firebaseAuth(fb);
        fbAuth.$authWithPassword({
            email: username,
            password: password
        }).then(function(authData) {
            $location.path("/todo");
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error("ERROR: " + error);
        });
    }
 
    $scope.register = function(username, password) {
        var fbAuth = $firebaseAuth(fb);
        fbAuth.$createUser({email: username, password: password}).then(function() {
            return fbAuth.$authWithPassword({
                email: username,
                password: password
            });
        }).then(function(authData) {
            $location.path("/todo");
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error("ERROR " + error);
        });
    }
```

When I try to sign in or register, there is an error message like this :

> ERROR: Error: Projects created at console.firebase.google.com must use
> the new Firebase Authentication SDKs available from
> firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

I tried to put this part of code in my html pages :

```js
var config = {
    apiKey: "xxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxx",
    databaseURL: "xxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxx"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

But it didn't solve my problem. I understood that it was an with the function, it is obsolete, but i don't know how to solve it (i'm a beginner). Ideas ?

**Thanks a lot.**

Comment: can you add info about your package.json which has firebase and angular-fire dependency, angular app config section and project structure?